# <input type="file"> showing first "All Files (*.*)" and not specific file type in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser, html-input

I have a the following code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qh72/)):

```
<input type="file" accept="application/xml">
```

In IE 10 and Chrome 29.0.1547.76 it filters directly for XML-Files. Only Firefox got the behaviour to show first all files. The Firefox file dialog has also the ".xml" filter, but it is on second position.

Is there a way to get Firefox using the ".xml" filter as standard filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been opened as a bug with Mozilla, there doesn't seem to be any movement on it so essentially there is currently no way to alter this:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/953914#answer-418899
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176